# Truncating log from first line

Tags: bash, logs, irc

I am making a simple IRC bot in bash and I want prevent its log from growing to infinity. For example it could be shortened always when reaching set number of lines. How can I do that easily? For example by cutting the file with removing first line(s)?

If possible, I would like to avoid sed/awk this time :)

Comment: Have you considered using logrotate?

Answer (score 2):

As jordanm said, `logrotate` is best.  But if you do want to roll your own,

```
tail -n 50 logfile.txt > logfile.new
mv logfile.new logfile.txt
```

would save only the last 50 lines.